# JavaScript Press Enter Key Twice With Different Actions After Each Keypress

Tags: javascript, keypress, keydown

I need help pressing the Enter key twice with a different action occurring after each keypress in pure JS (no jQuery), for example:

- Press Enter
- One action happens
- Press Enter again
- A different action happens

I can get the first action working, just not the second. Here's my code:

```
var enterPressed = 0;
window.onkeydown = function (e) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (keyCode === 13) { 
    if (enterPressed === 0) {
      enterPressed = 1;
      e.preventDefault(); 
      console.log("Enter pressed once. enterPressed is " + enterPressed);
    } else if (enterPressed === 1) {
      e.preventDefault(); 
      console.log("Enter pressed twice. enterPressed is " + enterPressed);
    }
   }
 };
```

[Here's a Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/VnN5w1cHeJz7wB8DLnUp?p=preview).

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: !!! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write `Note: as document.write writes to the document stream, calling document.write on a closed (loaded) document automatically calls document.open which will clear the document.` http://plnkr.co/edit/JQMTK4mC7cL0qrCMSkW7?p=preview

Comment: Updated to use console.log instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are throwing away all JS code when you write on "document".

You need to put that answer on another element like a , document.getElementById('result') and then write the result to that element.

[Here is your plunk good sir](http://plnkr.co/edit/o10FcrBDLlbfR0mcRwtD?p=preview)

```
var enterPressed = 0;
window.onkeypress = function (e) {
 var keyCode = (e.keyCode || e.which);
 if (keyCode === 13) {
  alert('key');
  if (enterPressed === 0) {
   enterPressed++;
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Enter pressed once. enterPressed is " + enterPressed;
  } else if (enterPressed === 1) {
   e.preventDefault(); 
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Enter pressed twice. enterPressed is " + enterPressed;
  }
 return;
 }
};
```